# Extending generic typealias

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods, type-alias

I have a generic typealias, for example

```
typealias StringArray = Array<String>
```

It is not possible to extend this like so:

```
extension StringArray {
    //Some methods
}
```

But is it possible in another way or have I to write

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    //Some methods
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that typealiases are just labels for existing types, so this:

```
extension StringArray {
    //Some methods
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
extension Array<String> {
    //Some methods
}
```

And that doesn't compile because it is not how extensions work. You must insert the `where` clause if you want to filter generics. For more information about extensions:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

For more information about generic `where` clauses in extensions: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID553